# Rotors - Slotted and cross drilled, are they better than OEM rotors?

Tags: brakes, dodge, grand-caravan, oem

I have a 2010 Grand Caravan which eats brakes.

In 75.000 Kms they have been done three times.

I'm wondering if slotted and cross drilled discs may be better than OEM?

It is mostly city driving  problem was so severe dodge doubled the initial warranty on brakes  figured problem may be heat generated ???

Comment: I highly doubt they'd help and suspect they may make your pads wear faster. How does your car eat brakes? As in the pads wear faster than expected? They wear unevenly? What type of pad is used? semi-metallic? ceramic? How's your driving style? Do you carry large loads in the van?

Comment: Wow, there is either something wrong with the car or the main driver rides the brakes constantly. People who ride the brakes really go through them.

Comment: Does "done three times" mean the brake pads were replaced, the brake rotors were replaced, or both?

Comment: Question.  Does the driver use their left foot or right foot to press the brake pedal?

Comment: My son wore out a brake job I did on his 92 Honda Accord in 13K miles, I used high quality rotors and pads. My mother could only get 30K on any car she drove. Low Miles on brakes is driver related in almost every case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [brake rotors- blank, slotted or drilled?](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/9148/brake-rotors-blank-slotted-or-drilled)

Comment: We have a 2009 and a 2011 Grand Caravan.  They're well known to eat brakes.  I've heard various explanations, but it seems to come down to the brakes being undersized for the vehicle size.  One person online said they bought performance brakes and the problem went away.  I went to my local mechanic with the '09 and mentioned the problem and he put "better" brakes on, with no problems since.  He said the difference was that the new ones had two brake cylinders on each disc instead of one.  Planning to do the same on the '11 when these ones wear out.

Comment: See this page at [carcomplaints.com](http://www.carcomplaints.com/Dodge/Grand_Caravan/2010/) - clearly we're not the only ones having problems with brakes.

Answer (score 8):

**No, you are best off with blank rotors(no slots, no holes) just like stock.**

1. Slotted rotors are more aggressive on the pads.
2. Drilled rotors are plain dangerous unless they are a good quality(read expensive) that were cast with holes in place not drilled after the casting. generally, cheap drilled rotors are for looks only. They are also less efficient in general as contact surface is less and heat dissipation suffers as well. They are also more aggressive on the pads.

**Here is what you can do:**

1. Pick up good quality Ceramic pads - they will last longer compared to the low quality organic or semi-metallic pads.
2. "turn" your rotors at the brake shop of there is thickness left to do so safely( shop will know if it's a good shop ), or get new ones - don't need any fancy ones - rockauto.com has great prices and that's where I get most of my parts. Brands like Centric or PowerStop are more then enough for daily driving. But do get blank without any slots or holes.
3. Adjust your braking habits - this will just improve life of your pads proportionally to the quality of your pads :)

**Potential reason your pads are eaten away so quickly:**

1. They are cheap organic pads that shops sells you and don't last long.
2. Your rotor surface is in bad condition and that affects the pad life as well.
3. You are hard on your brakes.
4. You drive down a long hill every single day.

Comment: Do rotors with holes drilled develop cracks?

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing It depends on the quality of the rotors and how hard they are run. They might, and assuming an average level of attention to details for a typical driver, it's safer to just get blank rotors.

Comment: The whole point to slotted or drilled rotors is to vent gas and dust created under severe braking loads, slotted is the preferred method these days....http://www.autoanything.com/brakes/drilled-or-slotted-rotors-what-are-the-best-brake-rotors.aspx

Comment: @Moab This was the point in 1960-70, when brake pads caused severe outgassing. Not any more. Here is example of the F1 brakes, ther eis no slots or drills... http://40.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lwiihh3Isq1qk65n6o3_r2_1280.jpg

Comment: The asker is taking about a normal passenger car, not F1 super car.

Comment: @Moab If F1 doesn't need slotted or drilled rotors, I believe asker doesn't need them as well. Also, neither you original comment, nor this one answers the original question - which was to "to increase pad life, should go with slotted/drilled rotos". Answer is NO.

Comment: Almost everyone should be using blank rotors.  Rarely there can be a case made for slotted in particular automotive racing applications.  Motorcycles use cross drilled, but you shouldn't on a car.

Answer (score 1):

Drilled and slotted rotors are used for racing cars or road cars driven very aggressively and perform well in rainy climates.There are many [benefits of drilled and slotted rotors](https://www.hexautoparts.com/blog/How-to-Choose-Brake-Rotors-Benefits-Of-Drilled-And-Slotted-Rotors.html) and they are a bit more expensive.

Comment: Unless the vehicle is going to be used in high speed situations, those slotted and drilled rotors are a waste of money.